# Film, seen 30 years ago, where a ship is traveling in some last ditch effort to a planet, that turns out to be earth

Tags: story-identification, movie

This film might have been foreign, not sure. The spoken language was not english, and the version I saw was subtitled. It was a feature film — not an episode of a T.V. serial.

Most of the film takes place aboard a ship on a long journey. They reach a planet, finally, which turns out to be earth.

What was the name of this film?

Comment: Was it live action or cartoon? What characters do you remember? Were they alien, did they look human? What kind of technology did they have? Any idea when it was made or how long ago you saw it? What makes you think it might have been foreign?

Comment: Must... resist... urge... to... say... Battlestar Galactica.

Comment: What's that you say, the answer rhymes with Mattletar Shalactica?

Comment: Battletruck Compactica

Comment: But seriously. How about Planet Of The Apes? (Except not much of the film takes place aboard the spaceship). Or if it's foreign, Солярис (Except the planet isn't Earth, but it reads the crew's minds and makes things appear from their memories, including Earth-like islands).

Comment: Define "foreign".

Comment: Did it end up being their "Earth" the planet they left or they came from another planet?!?

Comment: Come on guys..no. Not Battlestar Galactica. It was a non-english, subtitled film from over 30 years ago. A film, not a T.V. Episode. And no, not Planet of the Apes. I don't know about the russian film you mentioned, Lister. I'll check it out.

Comment: Was it animated? if so, check out legend of the galactic heroes, in it a couple of the chars make a journey to earth.

Comment: Maybe Sankukai? In English, "Message from Space". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_from_Space

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like Ice Pirates.

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087451/

Comment: No. Not Battlestar Galactica. It was a FILM not a tv show. I saw it, projected, in a theater. It was somewhat artsy, maybe foreign (again, not certain).

Comment: @ArthurFingle: Note that the original *series* Battlestar Galactica was heavily condensed into what appeared to be a small number of feature-length tv movies in some countries. As such, the difference may not seem as obvious to some posters as it does to you.

Answer (score -2):

Without trying to make a habit of answering [story-identification](/questions/tagged/story-identification) questions with [HHGTTG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy), this sounds familiar from two distinct incidents in that series.

Note that the tv series is roughly 30 years old.

## From the [second book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Restaurant_at_the_End_of_the_Universe)/[sixth tv episode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy_%28TV_series%29#Episode_6)

> It could be the "middle ship" of the [Golgafrinchans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_races_and_species_in_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Golgafrinchans) which eventually crashes on earth and turns out to be the actual origin of humanity.

## From the [fifth book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mostly_Harmless)

> Or it might be the ship of the [Grebulons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_races_and_species_in_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Grebulons), who are stranded near earth, monitoring and visiting it, to eventually invite the alternate version of Tricia McMillan to help them with their star charts.

Answer (score -2):

gonna have to definitely with first answeer  the movie has to be battlestar gallatiga , the 80s movie starring lorne greene sadly missed and also not to be confused with the tv series of same name , that was the spin off to the above movie .